# Azure Static Website is not showing updates after changes?

Tags: angular, azure

Please can you help ? I have an angular app on a Azure Static Website. I have made some changes and uploaded it to the site. I have confirmed the changes are there. However browser are still show the old JS. I have cleared the cache. Used different browsers.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. The CDN needed to be Purged.

Hope this helps someone